# Best Unmoderated Remote Usability Testing Tool?

Tags: usability, usability-testing

My name's Ivan and I am a UX Specialist in Belgium. Since we are a rather small UX team within a big company, we are trying to find ways to help us in our day-to-day activities. As such, we are currently trying to find a tool in order to perform **unmoderated remote usability testing** for our websites, so than we can keep focussing on our other activities (in-house moderated usability testing, eye tracking, user research, expert reviews on hardware & software products, etc.).

I'm actually benchmarking a few companies as UserZoom, Loop11, Userlytics, etc. and I wonder if one you guys already made use of one of them for remote website testing and if you could provide me with your thoughts about it.

Many of them provide video/audio recordings of test respondents, which is really powerful to get their actual feedback, but also very time-consuming if we need to review those video/audio recordings in order to issue a report.

As such, I would rather be looking first at tools that provide detailed analyses of the user tracking paths (first clicks, clickstream, completion rates, success/failures, page views, etc.). Does anyone of you use such a tool and if so, what do you think of it ? (pros, cons, drawbacks, etc.)

I'm currently focussing on **Loop11** as it seems to provide what I'm looking for without video/audio recordings, but I wonder if you ever used this tool and if it delivers what it promises.

Thanks for your feedback
Ivan

Comment: This question might be more on topic on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).